# Run Azure Databricks without Spark cluster

Tags: python, azure, databricks

I have used Domino Data Lab for a while and I was able to start a Python or R session with a single machine, without using Spark.

Is is possible to do the same with Azure Databricks? That is, to start a notebook session with Python without Spark (and a cluster)?

Comment: You must have a cluster, but it's perfectly possible to run code that doesn't use Spark at all.

Comment: Have you looked at Azure Notebooks? Maybe that’s good enough for your use case: https://notebooks.azure.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You always have to have a "cluster", but it can be a single node cluster (only with a driver node). Set the number of worker nodes to zero for this configuration. You are not able to run Spark on a driver-only cluster. See the following [example](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/applications/deep-learning/single-node-training/mxnet.html#use-mxnet-on-a-single-node) using MXNet on a driver-only cluster.

Another option that is available with [September 2020 platform release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/product/2020/september) is [Single Node Cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/single-node).
You can select "Single-Node" from the Cluster Mode to create a single-node cluster with Spark running in local mode.

Answer (score 3):

Databricks now has [single-node clusters](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/single-node.html) out in public preview.